# Previewing the ruby elements in html.erb with Aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, erb

I'm making my first rails app with Aptana studios and I'm trying to preview some of the basic partials I'm making to add to the other views. The problem I have is when I run them using Firefox/IE the ruby elements of the file get printed to screen as is and are not evaluated.

Is there a work around to get this to run the ruby elements properly either using Aptana's run/preview options or using another program.

Thanks for any help anyone has as it's starting to get frustrating after looking for solutions for 5 hours

-------------------------------- Edit

Code from _topnav.html.erb

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <% @categories.each do |c| %>
            <tr><%= c.name %></tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

code snippet from index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/topnav' %>
```

controller categories_controller.rb snippet

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end
```

When _topnav.html.erb is run this is seen on the web page

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %> <%= c.name %> <% end %>
```

When index.html.erb is run this is seen on the web page

```
<%= render 'shared/topnav' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a way to solve the problem.

Firstly I ran

```
rails server
```

on the command line in Aptana that set up the server for me.

Then I got up the internal web browser within Aptana under Windows->Show Views->Web Browser and went to the url of the page specified in routes.rb in this case http://localhost:3000/ as it was the root page and it finally evaluated the ruby code and it appeared as expected.

P.s Thanks for trying to help NibbleX

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that you have wrapped the Ruby inside your views within tags, this will ensure it is evaluated.

For .ERB the syntax is `<%= @ruby.code %>`

In .HAML a simple `= @ruby.code` will suffice

What are your views called if not html.haml or html.erb?

Comment: The view file I'm currently working on is index.html.erb but the routes and controllers for the file all work fine when using just html code. The syntax for the ruby uses <%=  ruby code %> or <%  hidden code %> but the actual code including the <% %> wrap gets printed within the html divs or table rather than processing the code.

Comment: Could you update your question with code snippets of your relevant controller and view please.

Comment: I've updated with some code snippets as far as I can tell the code is all alright but the I think its the way its run using Aptana

Comment: `<%= @categories.each do |c| %>`  add an '=' to the front of the tag, this will let Ruby know to output the result of the block.

Comment: It is still printing the tags and code to the web browser when run I also tried running it on the code academy Rails App tutorial by adding it to the code at the top of the page and it works as expected with that so it seems to be a problem with the way Aptana runs the code as it doesn't seem to evaluate any of the ruby code